Logo doesn't appear when head tag is called dynamically
So i am making a home for a website, but then i learned that i could call the <head>, <navbar>, <footer> dynamically so i won't need to change all the pages whenever there is an addition or removal.
I am currently making it with html css and js. so i finished my footer&navbar and it looks okay to me, the logo are being replaced by the logo from fontawesome. I then move the navbar & footer and calling it using "layout.js" and nothing changes. Until i move the head and calling it using the same javascript.
So far i tried to place a static content (inside main tag) as a mean to debug but it still doesn't appear in when i'm opening it using live server extension via VSC. i do plan to use bootstrap for this project, but so far i have just added the bootstrap via cdn. i placed it on top purposely so it won't changed my css.
here are the code
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head id="header"></head>
<body>
    <header id="navbar" class="navbar-container"></header>
    <main class="content-wrapper">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer" class="footer-container"></footer>
    <script src="assets/script/layout.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/script/subscription.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

layout.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  fetch('pages/nav.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      document.getElementById('navbar').innerHTML = data;
    });
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  fetch('pages/footer.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = data;
    });
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  fetch('pages/header.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = data;
    });
});


header.html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Home</title>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ad797e598.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

this is nav.html which i called to the index
<nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-logo">
        <a href="#">LOGO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-link">
        <a href="">Product</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-button">
        <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
<hr class="navbar-line">

i do look at the console to check the error but i didn't find any error related to the fontawesome logo. I am also wondering how to debug things like this incase i met another similar errors

It seems you want to manually implement client-side rendering, but what do you mean by "calling HTML" (header/footer)? Also, are your fetch() requests working (see Network tab in DevTools)? Is your JavaScript running as expected? Try to add some breakpoints and use your debugger, or (more simply) try to see what gets executed with some console.log()s.

So i checked on my laptop today and it is working as intended?? just to clarify i was making this question in my PC, i will get back to update as soon as i got home to check in my PC. but 1 thing for sure the code is the perfectly the same, nothings changed because i just pull it from my github.

The problem is that you are using a script element to embed fontawesome - but assignment to innerHTML does not execute script elements. For possible workarounds - see duplicates.

hey, just an update i did some small work from my laptop push it back to github. when i got home i pulled it and check the web using live server and the logo appears. idk what caused it

to give another update, i just wanted to highlight that CBroe answer is correct. i ended up using the CDN method to upload  the fontawesome as CSS. thanks for the help

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" />

use this line in your head part
